# Deploy application in example folder of flutter package

Tags: flutter, package

My company has an internal library with an app which is used inside the company. This app heavily uses the library. To test this heavily test this library using the company app I need to move this app to the example folder of the flutter package (internal library). How can I rename the app inside the example folder and configure deployment configurations for this app.

I understand this might not be suggested but we really need this to heavily test the library using integration tests and QA.

Is there any specific steps to do this in my case?

Comment: you might be looking for `Melos`

Comment: no. My project is not that big and doesn't need unnecessary seperation. The package just have example folder and I need to deploy it to appstore and playmarket for internal testing of the package. That's it